# Windows command line program that lists open sockets of certain process

Tags: sockets, cmd

I know that on windows I can type "netstat -an" and find open tcp connections.

But there is no information about the processes that own that tcp connections.

In Linux you get this info with "lsof".

Is there a free command line program that gives this information?

Comment: In MS-DOS there is no concept of "process". I don't think that it has TCP stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows 2000 and later, netstat can display the process ID for each open socket via the `-o` parameter, eg:

```
netstat -ano
```

See MSDN for more details:

[The netstat command can now display process IDs that correspond to active TCP or UDP connections in Windows 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907980)

[SysInternals TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) can display process names, and has both GUI and command-line interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

This will return the process ID for the process name in MSDOS

```
tasklist /svc | find "processName"
```

then you can plug that PID into netstat

```
netstat -ano | find "PID HERE"
```

I dont know how to connect it all together into a batch though.  I just know how to work in the command line.

Comment: for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2" %i in (`tasklist /svc`) do @if "%i"=="processName.exe" ( netstat -ano | find "%j" )

Answer (score 0):

Put this script in a batch file (eg  Mynetstat.bat) and give process name as argument.

```
Command : Mynetstat.bat <process name>
```

```
@echo off
set procName=%1
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%F in ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %1" /fo csv') do call :Foo %%~F
goto End

:Foo
set z=%1
echo netstat for : "%procName%" which had pid "%1"
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
netstat -ano |findstr %z%
goto :eof

:End
```